# Is it possible to look up the public key for a .onion-address?

Tags: onion-services, directory, protocol

I know `.onion` addresses are a (partial) hash of a descriptor which contains a public [RSA key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29), so I was wondering: it is possible to see the public key that is found when connecting to a `.onion` hidden service using Tor?

While in general it is a dangerous idea to use the same cryptographic key for different algorithms, there are many statistical reasons why knowing the public key is interesting. For example, looking for low-entropy keys by checking if the key is used by [others](https://www.eff.org/observatory) or [looking for common prime factors](http://windowsontheory.org/2012/05/15/979/).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In theory, it should be just a matter of fetching /tor/rendezvous2/<hidden service identity> via HTTP from the hidden service directory responsible for that hidden service, as per the [rend spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/rend-spec.txt), in particular section 1.6.

In practice, you need to find the right server to download it from and then form the request correctly.  That's a bit icky to do manually.  There is a script by DonnchaC, [retrieve_hs_descriptor](https://github.com/DonnchaC/tor/blob/master/scripts/retrieve_hs_descriptor.py), which depends on [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) and helps with that part.

As an example, right now the descriptor for the [DuckDuckGo hidden service](http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/) can be found, among other places, at

```
http://64.31.47.121:9030/tor/rendezvous2/yj446zqor4cczgxzl3kgtmdbfgwkj6de
```

and looks like this:

```
rendezvous-service-descriptor yj446zqor4cczgxzl3kgtmdbfgwkj6de
version 2
permanent-key
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBAJ/SzzgrXPxTlFrKVhXh3buCWv2QfcNgncUpDpKouLn3AtPH5Ocys0jE
aZSKdvaiQ62md2gOwj4x61cFNdi05tdQjS+2thHKEm/KsB9BGLSLBNJYY356bupg
I5gQozM65ENelfxYlysBjJ52xSDBd8C4f/p9umdzaaaCmzXG/nhzAgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
secret-id-part a2pcyuhciqsrah34benwufa54aandwzh
publication-time 2013-10-01 15:59:47
protocol-versions 2,3
introduction-points
-----BEGIN MESSAGE-----
//OUTPUT CUT
-----END MESSAGE-----
signature
-----BEGIN SIGNATURE-----
VEToDAxw1X77NwcM6/DG+I3uu8lLlFpI//rUHjLRC0unA7kRp6xY4E6xpcbl4KUX
EUUkJ3hXhmB3gFAjUkk70IDr5HIP86Z/ZTl6WvbTFWYLUPJQtt08XSmY788FG1lA
nTnNbqms5Nt5HKsG5khZf5viIuU3ei+u0SIv3gHy3JY=
-----END SIGNATURE-----
```

---

Note that for servers running a Tor version 0.2.4.x or 0.2.3.23 or later, the answer is even trickier.  Such servers, when acting as hidden service directories, will require these HTTP requests to be done [via an encrypted connection](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/tor-0.2.4.17-rc:/src/or/directory.c#l3284), i.e. over Tor and not using plain-text HTTP.  So that makes it a bit more tricky. The easiest approach might be to modify Tor and have it dump HS descriptors when you fetch them.

Otherwise you could use Stem [get_hidden_service_descriptor](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html) function. 
The following python script will print the HS descriptor for the onion address passed as command line parameter.

```
import sys
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate()
    print(controller.get_hidden_service_descriptor(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Didn't atagar or other folks make a python tool to fetch and dump hidden service details?

Comment: Maybe.  I just looked at Tor and adding a dump after the log_debug "Successfully stored rend desc" in rendcommon.c seemed like a straight-forward idea.  --  I also looked at the control spec but it seems we don't like talking about hidden services much.

Comment: Script linked, answer updated accordingly.

Comment: The retrieve_hs_descriptor link is currently dead, but there is https://stem.torproject.org/api/descriptor/hidden_service_descriptor.html.