# .onion Domains DNS lookup

Tags: onion-services, dns, protocol

How does Tor resolve `.onion` Domains? Are there also some central DNS servers in the Tor network that store these records? Is there a chance that two hidden services generate the same domain name?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't resolve them in the common sense - there is no DNS involved at all.

It looks up their introduction point on the hidden service directories - see [Is it possible to look up the public key for a .onion-address?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/244/is-it-possible-to-look-up-the-public-key-for-a-onion-address).

Then a rendezvous point is set up where the hidden service and the client meet -
answers to [How do onion addresses exactly work?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/672/how-do-onion-addresses-exactly-work/674#674) have more details.

The hostname is just the (truncated) hash of the public key - it's highly unlikely that two services create the same hostname.