# Visiting websites also run as hidden service

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, web-hosting

If you use TBB to visit a public website that also runs a hidden service for end-to-end encryption(DuckDuckGo for example), will TBB automatically use the hidden service or do users need to manually enter it's onion address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be done manually. There is no interaction between the Domain Name System (DNS) and Tor hidden service hostnames. See [this answer about resolution of .onion domains](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/711/onion-dns-lookup).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of custom HTTPS Everywhere rules which when installed would redirect you to the hidden service automatically where available.

https://github.com/chris-barry/darkweb-everywhere