# How is a .onion URL resolved?

Tags: onion-services, dns

I am interested in how a .onion url is resolved to a server in the Tor network. In the normal internet there is DNS, which is not used on the Tor network. How does the name resolution work there?

Comment: Duplicate of https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/711/onion-domains-dns-lookup

Comment: Okay, Thanks. Shoud i delete?